# Solving ODE $\arcsin x\frac {dy}{dx}+y\cot x=\frac{x^2}{e^{\sin x}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve for $y$:
$$\arcsin x\frac {dy}{dx}+y\cot x=\frac{x^2}{e^{\sin x}}$$

My original idea is to solve it using the integrating factor method since the equation can be altered into an equation in the form of: $$\frac {dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x)$$However, I find this extremely difficult, and it definitely seems like I can't use this method to solve it.

$\mathbf {Note}:$

I do not know the source of this problem, this was asked through a DM, so I have no clue of checking if the equation has been wrongly written. Attempted to solve it but to no success. Also, I am fairly new to solving ODE's, so I might not understand the solutions suggested.

Comment: I'm 99% certain that there is no elementary solution for this equation. One could classify how singular it is at $x=0$. Is the right side correct? $\exp(\frac{x^2}{\sin x})$ would also fit the vague pattern of this task.